# Revealing module pattern, undefined property

Tags: javascript, revealing-module-pattern

I have two files, *app.js* and *utils.js* that are concatenated together at build via Gulp.

I'm getting an error "Cannot read property 'getUrlParam' of undefined" when trying trying to set the app.mapYear value inside of my return statement.

Setting *app.mapYear* inside of the init function seems to work. I'm wondering why I'm unable to set *app.mapYear* in my return statement though.

Am I missing something simple here? Is there a better way? I'm hoping to prevent setting object properties sporadically throughout my code if I can do it in my return.

```
// app.js
//*****************
'use strict';

var app = app || {};
app = (function() {

    const getMapYear = () => {
        return app.utils.getUrlParam('year');
    };

    const mapYear = getMapYear();

    const init = () => {
        //init offcanvas menu
        $(document).foundation();

        // app.mapYear = mapYear();
    };

    return {
        init,
        mapYear
    };

})();

$(function() {
    app.init();
});


utils.js
//*****************

var app = app || {};

app.utils = (function() {

    const getUrlParam = () => {
        console.log(document.location.search);
        return document.location.search;
    }

    return {
        getUrlParam
    };

})();
```

Thanks for your time and suggestions!

**EDIT:** For anyone that's run into the same issue, here is how I resolved it given the responses provided.

When compiled, `utils.js` is first followed by `app.js`. My return statement in app.js looks like this:

```
return {
    init,
    utils: app.utils,
    mapYear: getMapYear()
};
```

Comment: Where are you defining `app.utils`? Why are you overwriting `app` with a new object?

Comment: My apologies, I forgot to mention that these files are concatenated together during my build process and that I'm not terribly experienced writing JS.

Comment: @ShatteredRib, You can see in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this order will work:

```js
//utils.js
//*****************

var app = app || {};

app.utils = (function() {

  const getUrlParam = () => {
    console.log(document.location.search);
    return document.location.search;
  }

  return {
    getUrlParam
  };

})();


// app.js
//*****************
'use strict';
//         |-- app contains the definition of (utils.js).
var app = app || {};
app = (function() {

  const getMapYear = () => {
    return app.utils.getUrlParam('year'); // You can use «app.utils».
  };

  const mapYear = getMapYear();

  const init = () => {
    //init offcanvas menu
    // $(document).foundation();

    // app.mapYear = mapYear();
  };

  return {
    init,
    mapYear,
    app
  };

})();

$(function() {
  app.init();
  console.log(app);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Danny, I tried this before posting my question but noticed that app.utils was not exposed to the window (though the console.log in utils does fire.) In Dev Tools, if I type in _app.utils_, it returns undefined.

Comment: Actually, app.js reveals only:  `init` and `mapYear`.

Comment: Agreed, but I wish to expose utils as well and I'm not sure how to make that happen with your suggested answer.

Comment: You can expose `app` as well. See my update, please.

Comment: I see what you're trying to show me. To get `utils` to be exposed as a direct property of `app`, I set it's key to `app.utils` inside of `app.js`. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In `app.js`, you're calling `getMapYear` before the contetns of `utils.js` have been evaluated and `app.utils` has been defined:

```
const mapYear = getMapYear();
```

Therefore, `app.utils` is undefined and you can't call any method of it. You would have to call `getMapYear` when `utils.js` has finished loading:

```
// in the app.js closure
const getMapYear = () => {
  return app.utils.getUrlParam('year');
};

const init = () => {
  //init offcanvas menu
  $(document).foundation();

  app.mapYear = getMapYear(); // call getMapYear later    
};
```

Make sure the `app.utils` object already exists when calling a method of it.

*Note*: In this approach however, `app.mapYear` exists only after you called `app.init()`.

Comment: I thought this might be the issue, too. I  simplified the code for my question. But I also have a _base.js_ file that loads in before _utils.js_. _base.js_ uses a utils method that calls a loading spinner to display. That method runs without issue which is why I was puzzled.

Comment: @ShatteredRib If you call a utility method in `base.js`, then I suppose it's like in my answer: `base.js` is loaded first, then `util.js` is loaded, then after some time, you call the utility method.